# Have static site on Amazon S3 and Cloudfront, how to add sub-domain hosted elsewhere?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, dns

I have a site with a root domain (mysite.com) as a jekyll static page, hosted on Amazon S3 and Cloudfront.  I'd like to add a sub-domain such as purchase.mysite.com which would be located on another provider such as Heroku.  The intention here is to have a landing page backed with Amazons CDN and the services somewhere else as at that point I don't think the speed is as important.  Has anyone else gone this route?  How and what was involved with it's implementation?  Is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup is pretty common I'd imagine.

You need to create a subdomain on your DNS using a CNAME record type pointing at the .herokuapp.com address that Heroku will give your application and then add the custom domain to your Heroku application.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Awesome, I'll give it a try in the morning and report back.